# KineticJs - Is it possible to drag an image behind the another(transparent,larger) image

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs, hidden, layer

my project is similar to www.logolenses.com in which you can add pre-made designs and move them behind trasparent image. In my project, when i make designs layer draggable, i still cant move it because it is under transparent layer. Then i tried to use hidden layer on top and make group with design so that they can move together. but when i add group to a layer design moves to top with hidden layer. For more example, Suppose you have draw layers a, b, c after another (a is bottom, b is mid, c is top) is there any way to drag a & c together without breaking that layer order? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: An intermediate layer (b) is interfering with the dragging you want to do on outside layers (a & c)

Solution: You tell the layer b to stop listening for events.

Layer b will still display, but layers a & c can drag without b interfering.

```
layerB.setListening(false)
```

Of course, if you later need to drag on layer b, just turn listening back on.